# Docker-in-Docker Pytest Failing with temp paths

Tags: docker, docker-in-docker

We do all our development in containers, and one of our applications manages docker via [docker-py](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) in production. So testing becomes docker-ception (docker in docker). We mount the host docker.sock via compose for development (ie mount the volume `/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock` which docker-py uses directly.

Many tests use the `tmp_path` pytest fixture (or library-specific temp paths) and those tests fail with a collection of random errors - mostly file not found, module not found etc.

Running the same procedures by hand and outside the dev container work.

Why come?

Comment: (This sounds like you're using the host Docker daemon, not DinD: you're not running a second Docker daemon in a container.)

Comment: Yep, host daemon, so technically docker-next-to-docker, however it's very DinD like in that the docker orchestration is all being done in the first container (including the build and run of the second container)

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR

the `/tmp` folder needs to be mounted as a volume in the dev environment.
adding

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - /tmp:/tmp
```

makes the temporary assets from testing available to the child container.

#### Long-winded answer

Docker-in-docker using the host `docker.sock` creates the containers as siblings, not nested children. This means the docker filesystem references from parent->child won't work because they are accessing the same filesystem as the host.

```
               #### /tmp files in parent not accessible to child ####

# on host machine                    # dev-container                                           
/                                    /                                                    
|__/home/sven/Repos/dev              |_/app  # mounted to /home/sven/Repos/dev in host    
|__/tmp # sub-container looks here!  |_/tmp  # pytest creates tmp files here                                            
|__/lib                              |... etc
|... etc
```

#### When Debugging

- remember to check the filetype of the files inside the child container to see if they
  actually mounted. **Docker will create empty directories for each file it cannot find on the host**. So if `main.py` did not actually mount, there will be a `main.py` directory in the container.